# No Such Key error when unzipping multi folder directory with Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, bytesio, python-zipfile

I'm using Lambda to unzip files in S3 using boto3, Zipfile (as zf), and BytesIO. When the function is triggered, the following code runs (I have already initalized the s3 client at this point. I used [this example](https://medium.com/@johnpaulhayes/how-extract-a-huge-zip-file-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket-by-using-aws-lambda-and-python-e32c6cf58f06) for the basis of my code. The **bucketname** and **zip_key** values are found without issue. The **s3_uri** is also generated appropriately. :

```
    bucketname = event["Records"][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    zip_key = event["Records"][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    s3_uri = 's3://'+bucketname+'/'
    
    #get zip folder from S3
    zip_obj = s3_client.Object(bucket_name=bucketname, key=zip_key)

    #create IO buffer
    buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
    
   
    z = zf.ZipFile(buffer)

    for filename in z.namelist():
        file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
        
        #Ignore folders generated by Mac zip operation
        if "__MACOSX" in str(file_info):
            print("")
        else:
            s3_client.meta.client.upload_fileobj(z.open(filename),Bucket=bucketname,Key=f'output/{filename}')
```

When running the code, I get the following error when creating the IO buffer:

```
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 22, in lambda_handler
    buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
```

The zip file has a main folder, with 4 subfolders, each with Excel files in them that need to be read and processed. I noticed this works with a zip file with a single excel file in it, however it doesn't work with multiple folders with files within them. Am I missing something in operation when creating the IO buffer? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem not in the zip file, problem is in the `s3_client.Object`, which doesn't have key `Body`. Possibly, URI is incorrect?

Comment: When I unzip a zip file that contains a single document, I have no issues getting the data from S3, which makes me think that the s3_client call isn't the issue

Comment: Ok, could you split the string `buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())` into two strings:
obj_body = zip_obj.get()["Body"]  
buffer = BytesIO(obj_body.read())
?

After this, you can see, which string produces an error.